# Borgmatic: deal with multiple different relative paths

Tags: debian, borg-backup

I'm using borgmatic to backup my whole server. As I'm runing LVM, I mount LVM snapshots to `/media/..` and back them up.

```
   source_directories:
    - /media/snapshot-root/
    - /media/snapshot-var/
    - /data/home
```

That results in paths inside the backup beginning with `/media/snapshot-root/` which is ugly, hard to understand and unnecessary. For example If I want to restore `/etc` I have to take a look into `/media/snapshot-root/etc`.

I know that there is an option

> Working directory for the "borg create" command. Tildes are
> expanded. Useful for backing up using relative paths. See
> http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/create.html for
> details. Defaults to not set.
> working_directory: /path/to/working/directory

But this does not help for multiple different paths. I also know that `cd`ing into the desired root path would work, but I cannot `cd`into three different paths.

The only soluition i found was setting each directory to a single file in `/etc(borgmatic.d/` but as I already use this for two different locations I would rather avoid it.